# Limit of sequence of integral related i.i.d. observations

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, asymptotics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Let $\hat F_n$ be their *modified* empirical distribution function, i.e.,
$$
\hat F_n(x)=\frac1{n+2}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{X_i\le x\}}\right)
$$
for every $x$, where $1_A$ is [the characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of the event $A$.

I wish to prove
$$
\sqrt n\int_{0}^1\Phi^{-1}(u)\left(\Phi^{-1}(\hat F_n(u))-\Phi^{-1}(u)\right)du\to 0
$$
in probability
as $n\to\infty$ with $\Phi$ is the cumulative normal distribution function.

It can be proved that $\Phi^{-1}(\hat F_n(x))=\Phi^{-1}(u)+O_p(1/\sqrt n)$. But then, I couldn't handle my integral.

Comment: Convergence to zero in which sense? The LHS is a random variable... And did you try to apply the reduction I explained to answer your other question? (I reformulated some minor aspects of your question, please meditate these changes and do not use again the same faulty formulations in your next questions.)

Comment: Thanks @Did for your suggestions. The convergence to zero what I meant us of course in the sense convergence in probability.

Comment: You should precise what you are denoting with $\Phi$, although I guess it is the CDF of a gaussian random variable.

Comment: Should the bounds of integration be $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @PseudoRandom: Yes Exactly. I have edited there. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @WillNelson: No, the bounds are $0$ to $1$.

Comment: So $F$ is a cumulative distribution function, which maps $(\infty,+\infty)$ to $[0,1]$, right? Since the expression $F(u)$ appears in your integrand, that suggests the range of $u$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @WillNelson, I have edited there.

Comment: Another problem with wording. I badly misinterpreted what the distribution of each $X_i$ is. Since you introduce their cumulative distribution function $F$, I assumed $F$ was arbitrary. I now see you mean something like "$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$". Please edit for clarity and remove the unused reference to $F$. Thx.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your suggestions.